# SQL select query that selects a row if one of the columns has one of many values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write query that selects rows depending on whether or not a column has a value "N" "Z" "P" or "Q". If that is in the column, then that row is selected and returned....

How do I do that?

I wrote a query that used a lot of or statements, but I have two other specifications that were not connected to each of the Or statements.

How to solve this?

Comment: Where columnName in ('N','Z','P','Q')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column IN ('N', 'Z', 'P', 'Q');
```

Comment: Ah yeah, actually since asking I realized that, but earlier I had abandoned that when I used a double quote instead of a single quote and got an error that it couldn't find a table "n".